# Flashing a Firmware to a router which doesnt have an "upgrade" page in its website interface

Tags: router, firmware, flashing

i need to flash my router because it is missing a lot of options in the configurations because my ISP installed their custom firmware,and the problem is i cant find the "upgrade" page because they removed it from the Web page interface
so is there another way to install another firmware or exploiting it or somehow uploading the firmware

### - ***some informations about my router:***

- Model: Huawei EchoLife HG8245H GPON Terminal

### - some Nmap outputs:

### Kernel:

Running: Linux 3.X

OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3.5

OS details: Linux 3.5

### Ports:

21/tcp filtered ftp

22/tcp filtered ssh

23/tcp filtered telnet

53/tcp open     domain   (generic dns response: REFUSED)

80/tcp open     ssl/http

Comment: Hello Thuglife, welcome to superuser. Have you contacted your ISP? The fact that the router "is missing a lot of options" may be related to the type of service contract you have with them. If the router belongs to your ISP, I'd strongly advise against reflashing it.

Comment: hey jaume, no i dont want to contact them, because they are assholes lol , they somehow disabled the ethernet ports that belong to their routers and they want me to pay 10$ for each port to enable them, and i dont want to do that i just need to reflash it no matter what